# Internal resistance for a fluid flowing in pipe

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, viscosity

Lets say we have a fluid moving in a pipe with velocity v.  what would be the resistance faced by it? in our class, the professor told us that internal resistance faced by fluid is given by R=8nl/pir^4 (from poiseuilles equation) but my doubt is , wont the viscous force(F=nAdv/dy)  acting on fluid serve as resistance? whats the difference between these two?

Answer (score 1):

There is no one true formula in this case.

Poiseuilles equation is for laminar flow. There are formulas for more complex flow types, like turbulent or even accounting for transitional region, but I guess it is not important for you.

And even for laminar flow there are different versions of the flow, depending how the boundary layer at the edge transitions into more gradual speed distribution in the middle of the flow.

First formula also accounts for a round pipe, and second one does not. Can you redo the second formula so that it makes sense for a round pipe? It wont be obvious, especially taking into account how different regions in the flow interact. But if you do, formulas would be more similar.

You can try to calculate an example to see how different the answer is, is it just a constant difference or does it change seemingly randomly?

Anyway, I try to use formulas that are as close to my situation as possible, unless I'm absolutely sure how the formula works. Too many nuances.